# Moving texture according to position in shader

Tags: unity, shaders, shaderlab

**Divinity Original Sin** have beautiful particle effect , When I move around game I see galaxy through particle that move according to my position.how can I make like it?

you can see this effect here:
https://youtu.be/4fIpQZ2sIAY

[image: 2017-12-28_11-42-01]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: record_2017_12_28_20_34_11_392]

usually uv coordinate used for uvmapping but here
Instead of using uvcoordinate use position!

```
Shader "Custom/ViewMode1"
{ 
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("_Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _Size("Size",Vector) = (1,1,1,1)
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="true" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
        ZWrite Off Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha Cull Off

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color    : COLOR;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            fixed4 _Color;
            float _Speed;
            float4 _Size;


            v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
            {
                v2f OUT;
                OUT.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN.vertex);
                OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
                OUT.color = IN.color;
                return OUT;
            }

            float4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
            {
                float2 screen = i.vertex.xy/_ScreenParams.xy;
                float4 tex = tex2D(_MainTex, screen /_Size)*i.color;
                return tex*_Color;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

also you can use `Tex2Dproj` try this:

```
Shader "Custom/ViewMode2"
{
    Properties{
        _MainTex("MainTex",2D) = "white"{}
        _Scale("Scale",Vector) = (1,1,1,1)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        // Draw ourselves after all opaque geometry
        Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" }

        // Grab the screen behind the object into _BackgroundTexture
        GrabPass
        {
            "_BackgroundTexture"
        }

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        // Render the object with the texture generated above, and invert the colors
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"



            struct v2f
            {
                float4 grabPos : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            };

            struct appdata {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };
            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _Scale;

            v2f vert(appdata v) {
                v2f o;
                // use UnityObjectToClipPos from UnityCG.cginc to calculate 
                // the clip-space of the vertex
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                // use ComputeGrabScreenPos function from UnityCG.cginc
                // to get the correct texture coordinate
                o.grabPos = ComputeGrabScreenPos(o.pos);

                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _BackgroundTexture;

            half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                half4 bgcolor = tex2Dproj(_MainTex, i.grabPos/_Scale);
                return bgcolor;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

[image: record_2017_12_28_20_19_04_91]

```
Shader "Smkgames/Particles/OriginalSin" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Particle Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _BackGround("BackGround",2D) = "white"{}
        _InvFade ("Soft Particles Factor", Range(0.01,3.0)) = 1.0
        _Scale("Scale",Vector) = (1,1,1,1)

        _Hue ("Hue", Range(0, 1.0)) = 0
        _Saturation ("Saturation", Range(0, 1.0)) = 0.5
        _Brightness ("Brightness", Range(0, 1.0)) = 0.5
        _Contrast ("Contrast", Range(0, 1.0)) = 0.5
    }

    Category {
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent" "PreviewType"="Plane" }
        Blend One OneMinusSrcColor
        ColorMask RGB
        Cull Off Lighting Off ZWrite Off


        SubShader {
            GrabPass
            {
                "_BackgroundTexture"
            }
            Pass {

                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                #pragma target 2.0
                #pragma multi_compile_particles
                #pragma multi_compile_fog

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                sampler2D _MainTex,_BackGround;
                fixed4 _TintColor;

                struct appdata_t {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    fixed4 color : COLOR;
                    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;

                };

                struct v2f {
                    float4 grabPos : TEXCOORD3;
                    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                    fixed4 color : COLOR;
                    fixed4 hsbc : COLOR1;
                    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                    UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
                    #ifdef SOFTPARTICLES_ON
                    float4 projPos : TEXCOORD2;
                    #endif
                };

                float4 _MainTex_ST;
                float4 _Scale;

                //__________Hue Saturation Brightness Contrast___________

                fixed _Hue, _Saturation, _Brightness, _Contrast;


                inline float3 applyHue(float3 aColor, float aHue)
                {
                    float angle = radians(aHue);
                    float3 k = float3(0.57735, 0.57735, 0.57735);
                    float cosAngle = cos(angle);

                    return aColor * cosAngle + cross(k, aColor) * sin(angle) + k * dot(k, aColor) * (1 - cosAngle);
                }

                inline float4 applyHSBCEffect(float4 startColor, fixed4 hsbc)
                {
                    float hue = 360 * hsbc.r;
                    float saturation = hsbc.g * 2;
                    float brightness = hsbc.b * 2 - 1;
                    float contrast = hsbc.a * 2;

                    float4 outputColor = startColor;
                    outputColor.rgb = applyHue(outputColor.rgb, hue);
                    outputColor.rgb = (outputColor.rgb - 0.5f) * contrast + 0.5f;
                    outputColor.rgb = outputColor.rgb + brightness;
                    float3 intensity = dot(outputColor.rgb, float3(0.39, 0.59, 0.11));
                    outputColor.rgb = lerp(intensity, outputColor.rgb, saturation);

                    return outputColor;
                }
                //_______________________________________________________________________

                v2f vert (appdata_t v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    #ifdef SOFTPARTICLES_ON
                    o.projPos = ComputeScreenPos (o.vertex);
                    COMPUTE_EYEDEPTH(o.projPos.z);
                    #endif
                    o.color = v.color;
                    o.texcoord = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord,_MainTex);
                    UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
                    o.grabPos = ComputeGrabScreenPos(o.vertex);
                    o.hsbc = fixed4(_Hue, _Saturation, _Brightness, _Contrast);

                    return o;
                }

                sampler2D_float _CameraDepthTexture;
                float _InvFade;

                fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
                {
                    #ifdef SOFTPARTICLES_ON
                    float sceneZ = LinearEyeDepth (SAMPLE_DEPTH_TEXTURE_PROJ(_CameraDepthTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.projPos)));
                    float partZ = i.projPos.z;
                    float fade = saturate (_InvFade * (sceneZ-partZ));
                    i.color.a *= fade;
                    #endif

                    half4 col = i.color * tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord);
                    col.rgb *= col.a;
                    UNITY_APPLY_FOG_COLOR(i.fogCoord, col, fixed4(0,0,0,0)); // fog towards black due to our blend mode
                    half4 bgcolor = tex2Dproj(_BackGround, i.grabPos/_Scale);
                    float4 hsbcColor = applyHSBCEffect(bgcolor, i.hsbc);
                    hsbcColor.rgb *= col.a;

                    return hsbcColor;
                }
                ENDCG 
            }
        } 
    }
}
```