# How can I write a dots effect shader when the character is behind an object?

Tags: unity, shaders, cg

I watched an interesting effect while I was playing Super Mario Odyssey: when Mario or another character was behind an obstacle (walls, etc), a tiny gray silhouette mesh appears.

I tried to build something similar using an amplify shader with Unity but I could not achieve it.

How could I write this?

Here is an example from the game:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Amplify forum I found this shader:

> We've performed some changes to the XRay sample in order to allow for the effect that you've requested.
>
> Here's a package that contains updated shaders, together with materials and >sample scene:
>
> [XrayWithIntersections.unitypackage](http://amplify.pt/forum/download/file.php?id=337)
>
> http://amplify.pt/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=710

you can easily make this effect by using `ZTEST Operators`:

render first pass by unlit gray color and `ZTEST Greater` ,`ZWrite Off`.

[image]

as you can see when mario is behind of something it will be gray:

[image]

then render second pass Albedo by `ZTest Default(ZTEST LEqual)`:

[image]

to making dots effect you can sample your texture by screen [space-mapped texture sample](http://wiki.amplify.pt/index.php?title=Unity_Products:Amplify_Shader_Editor/Compute_Screen_Pos) or [dithering](http://wiki.amplify.pt/index.php?title=Unity_Products:Amplify_Shader_Editor/Dither).

[image]

I wrote this shader without Amplify:

```
Shader "Custom/Mario/DotsBehindWall" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Dots("Dots",2D) = "white"{}
        _Size("Size",Vector) = (1,1,1,1)
        _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0

    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        GrabPass
        {
            "_BackgroundTexture"
        }

        ZWrite Off
        ZTest Greater


        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float4 grabPos : TEXCOORD1;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex,_Dots;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float4 _Size;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                float2 screen = i.vertex.xy/_ScreenParams.xy;
                float4 tex = tex2D(_Dots, screen /_Size);
                return tex;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
        ZWrite On
        ZTest LEqual 

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
            fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            o.Metallic = _Metallic;
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

another way to make this effect is using stencil buffer that I explained In [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/152824/how-can-i-create-a-see-behind-walls-effect/152825#152825)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was a bit busy, I test what you wrote, it works fine, but what I want is that tiny dots, another thing is I'm using "fade" on the render mode from standard shaders for hair materials and this shader you wrote doesn't work on this mode, either way you other post is interesting as well, thanks.

Comment: @LobsangWhite ok I will update my answer.for tiny dots you can use [dithering](https://github.com/gkjohnson/unity-dithered-transparency-shader) or using dots texture that mapped by [this method](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/152609/moving-texture-according-to-position-in-shader/152610#152610)

Comment: Nice, like a glove, dithering is an interesting option as well. Thanks.